# Autoload own and packagist classes in module

Tags: module, magento2.2

I'm creating a module, which uses a range of its own classes as well as packagist modules

Running on its own outside magento, my composer.json is:

```
{
    "name": "root/importer",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "jochendaum",
            "email": "jd@myemail"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Zenith\\": "classes"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "nicolab/php-ftp-client": "^1.4",
        "league/csv": "^9.1"
    }
}
```

But when I transfer this into my module under directory

/app/code/Zenith/Importer

it doesn't work after running bin/magento setup:upgrade .Both my own classes and packagist classes are not found.

Comment: have you checked in `vendor` folder?

Comment: @kunj checked for what? the packagist installed files are all in a local vendor folder, but setup:upgrade does not install anything into Magento's vendor folder. I'm not sure it should. How is autoload in a magento module supposed to work? I don't mean autoload *of* the module class, but rather autoloading other classes